# What is the best configuration for 10000 blocking Actors with a custom dispatcher

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-http

As the title says, currently there are 1000 actors which does a blocking call, which is a really slow webservice call (20 seconds req timeout time). Currently I have configured a fork join executor with 40 max parallelism.

I am using a round robin router for actor routing. In case it does routed to all the 1000 actors the incoming message frequency is higher than the produced response frequency. So I would need to increase the number of actors created. Lets say we had increased the no of actors to 10000 and what should be the optimum dispatcher for such scenario. I know this is not a good design but it is the only design that I am able to work on.
Sorry for not posting any code snippets since posting this from mobile at 3 am.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify: Why do you want to use Akka actors for blocking calls - can you simply use Future?

Comment: Also, thread-pool-executor is preferred in terms of blocking operations, see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/dispatchers.html#solution-dedicated-dispatcher-for-blocking-operations

Comment: To expand on @YikSanChan comment - you could: create 1 HTTP client per webservice (perhaps with a dedicated thread pool), create a request queue within an actor, schedule a call using Future, make that Future send response to Actor, let the Actor handle receiving orders, checking if queue is not too big (then it could immediately respond with failure) or redirecting result from client. This way you would have a non-blocking actor and the only blockade would be in HTTP client.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I am considering that HTTP client implementation in the actor level.